# Twitter Bootstrap Modal - horizontal resize?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, resize, modal-dialog

I know there are lots of answers on how to resize the modal vertically, but how can I do it horizontally (preferably, in a responsive manner)? Every time I try I end up committing a felony against CSS.

**Edit** - I'm trying to put in a `<table>` in the modal with multiple columns, if it matters. The columns extend beyond the small modal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add some css rules to the modal to set the width.

```
width: 900px
```

if you need a responsive manner, try using @media in css. for example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .modal {
    width: 800 px
  }
}
```